# The same vs it usage

Tags: pronouns

> 1) He bought a house and is living in **the same**.
>
> 2)He bought a house and is living in **it**.

I thought both are correct. But my grammar book is saying first form is wrong and we should use second form. Why so? What is the difference in meaning

Comment: Both are grammatical. If you say the first, you sound like an office memo from the 1950s, not like an English speaker. The most natural form would be _and is living there_.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *the same* is a rather formal and archaic way of referring to something named earlier in the sentence. It isn't ungrammatical, we just wouldn't use it in everyday life.

Comment: I have seen 'the same' and just 'same' used in Indian office language, but in Western English they are so outdated as to be errors.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a mistake. Here, 'the same' means 'it'.

Examples:

- You had given your book. Give me it (= the same) again, please.
- I have received your invitation. Thank you for it (= the same).
- He bought a house and he is living in it (= the same).
- But using 'the same' here is very traditional and formal.

It is better to replace 'the same' by the adverb of place 'there' and 'is' with 'has been':

- He bought a house and has been living there.